# Angular 2 ngrx route-view issue

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing, ngrx

I'm trying to use `ngrx/router`, however whenever I try to use the tag `<route-view></route-view>` I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not observable

If i remove it the error goes away. I'm obviously unable to display my routes because of this. I can make the url change by click a `[link-to]` but this doesn't matter if `route-view` doesn't work in displaying the data in that component.

I'm using Angular 2, webpack, and trying to use `ngrx/router` as mentioned.